# Use of category and alertAction in PushNotificationIOS in react-native

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, push-notification, react-native

I am using `PushNotificationIOS` API in `react-native` to show local notifications. In the `details` object used to show the local notification, I don't completely understand the use of two fields

1. `alertAction` - Is this only used to change the text shown in the footer of the notification from default `view` to something else or could it be used for some other purpose also. I was thinking if we could have custom actions in the notifications and attach custom handlers to such actions. Could the alertAction be used to fulfill that requirement?
2. `category` - I am not sure how to use this field. The official documentation says it is required for actionable notifications. What are actionable notifications? In the example usage on the documentation, `category` is set to `REACT_NATIVE` but I am not sure what purpose does it solve.

Any input will be much appreciated.

Comment: The docs is quite poor. Did you find the answer?

Comment: The `category` can be used to specify the notification actions to show for the notifications. The notification actions appears if you slide the notification towards the left. If none are configured, then you will only see a cross sign. You can check out more about notification actions here https://github.com/holmesal/react-native-ios-notification-actions. This repo is specifically for react native. The `alertAction` can be used to specify the string that will appear below the notification. For e.g., usually you would see 'slide to unlock'

Comment: @VarunGupta Did you find any other info/solutions about how is possible to customize and attach custom handlers to such actionsalert?